# Singular to plural noun

Tags: grammatical-number, phonology, middle-english, inflectional-morphology, irregular-plurals

Many nouns that end in *‑f* are made plural by changing the *‑f* to *‑v‑* and
adding *‑es*.

```
+----------+-----------+
| Singular |   Plural  |
+----------+-----------+
|  half    |  halves   |
|  leaf    |  leaves   |
|  shelf   |  shelves  |
+----------+-----------+
```

[image]

But some nouns that end in *‑f* are made plural simply by adding *‑s*.

```
+----------+-----------+
| Singular |   Plural  |
+----------+-----------+
|  chief   |  chiefs   |
|  roof    |  roofs    |
|  cliff   |  cliffs   |
+----------+-----------+
```

Some nouns that end in *‑f* can be made plural in two ways, either by adding *‑s* or *‑ves*:

```
+----------+--------------------+
| Singular |      Plural        |
+----------+--------------------+
|  scarf   |  scarfs or scarves |
|  hoof    |  hoofs or hooves   |
|  dwarf   |  dwarfs or dwarves |
|  wharf   |  wharfs or wharves |
+----------+--------------------+
```

Now my question is how to determine whether to use only *‑s* or to change the *‑f* to *‑v‑* and add *‑es*?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_irregular_plurals_ending_in_%22-ves%22

Comment: These are called 'irregular' plurals for a reason. Sadly, I'm not sure you will find any rule that can be applied to an unfamiliar case.

Comment: i have spent 2 days in finding reason  :( now it comes with **irregular** plurals (i had no idea about that before now) ... thankyou

Comment: If you've studied German you know there is a lot of variation in Germanic noun plurals. English has lost **most** of it; but some remains. Notice also that this extends to other fricatives: /mauθ/ optionally becomes /mauðz/ in the plural (/mauθs/ also occurs). And the voicing occurs again in distinguishing the verb from the noun -- _He mouths_ /mauðz/ _the words; _He interleaves the pages_, etc.

Comment: "Make like a tree and ... go."

Comment: @Mitch tree of ___leaves___ or ___leafs___ ?? :P

Comment: The plural _dwarves_ is not universally endorsed for non-fictional persons ( http://grammarist.com/usage/dwarfs-dwarves/ ).

Comment: There's a series puns of the form "Make like an X and (do something like an X that also sounds like you're moving away)". Here it is "Make like a tree and leave". There is then the meta joke from "Back to the Future" where [Biff, who is a stupid bully, says "Make like a tree and get outta here"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Rze0XkDUqQ) (thanks @snailboat)

Comment: It should be noted also that homonymity of certain nouns with their verb counterparts can (and should) inform a preference in cases where there is coexistence of both the 's' and 'v' forms. 

It creates a useful distinction between the 3rd-person-singular-present form of the verb and the plural of the homonymic noun to have the verb (e.g. "scarfs [down food]") take the 's' alone and the noun should take the 'v' form (e.g. "scarves").

This has not caught on in all cases (not many would write "halfs" to refer to more than one half, for instance) but hopefully will still help you decide.

Comment: The plural of "Roof" can be "Roofs" or "Rooves", the latter being the more correct usage. "Dwarfs" used to be the sole correct pluralisation of "Dwarf", until Tolkein popularised "Dwarves", and "Dwarves" usually carries a fantasy connotation while "Dwarfs" usually refers to the actual medical condition. (It might seem a bit strange and out-of-touch with reality to refer to Peter Dinklage and Warwick Davis collectively as "Dwarves" rather than "Dwarfs")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a rule to determine whether to pluralise -f singular nouns as -fs or -ves. It is a matter of custom. A good dictionary should indicate which forms are acceptable (one or both can be).

Apropos to this, Tolkien pluralised some -f singular nouns in unconventional ways. He pluralised "elf" as "elves", where "elfs" had been common, and pluralised "hoof" as "hoofs", where "hooves" is common. It was his style preference, though choosing the less common form may throw the reader.

Comment: Untrue.  The plural of *elf* has always been *elves* (well, ever since singular *ælf* stopped becoming plural *ælfe*).  It’s *dwarves* whose older-looking form he recalled, to make it seem equivalent in antiquity to *elves*. However, you are correct that he did use the form *hoofs* 30 times across *The Silmarillion*, *The Hobbit*, and *The Lord of the Rings*, as compared with using the *hooves* form only 5 times across the same corpus.

Comment: Regarding ***-f > -ves***, J.R.R. Tolkien also notably pluralized ***turf*** as ***turves***: “The oldest kind were, indeed, no more than built imitations of smials, thatched with dry grass or straw, or roofed with **turves,** and having walls somewhat bulged.” and “For after three days the Men of the Mark prepared the funeral of Théoden; and he was laid in a house of stone with his arms and many other fair things that he had possessed, and over him was raised a great mound, covered with green **turves** of grass and of white evermind.” and other examples besides.

Answer (score 2):

There are only a few words which you should pluralize by changing the **f** or **fe** to **v** and adding **es**. They are as follows:

> Singular ending in **f**
>
> - **beef** to beeves (or beefs)
> - **calf** to calves
> - **corf** to corves
> - **dwarf** to dwarves (but only in Tolkein)
> - **elf** to elves
> - **half** to halves
> - **hoof** to hooves
> - **leaf** to leaves
> - **loaf** to loaves
> - **ourself** to ourselves
> - **scarf** to scarves (or scarfs)
> - **self** to selves
> - **sheaf** to sheaves
> - **staff** to staves or (staffs)
> - **shelf** to shelves
> - **themself** to themselves
> - **thief** to thieves
> - **wharf** to wharves (or wharfs)
> - **wolf** to wolves
> - **yourself** to yourselves
>
> Singular ending in **fe**
>
> - **knife** to knives
> - **life** to lives
> - **wife** to wives

Also, *Oaf* to *oaves* appears to be an archaic form, with *oafs* being correct now. Ditto *roof* to *rooves*, with *roofs* being the current accepted plural form.

So, keep this list. You could probably even memorize them. By my count, that's only 21 words, and a few of those are generally uncommon.

You must also remember that if a compound word ends with one of the words that uses the **ves** ending to pluralize, the compound word will do the same. For example, *knife* changes to *knives*, so *penknife* will change to *penknives*, and *wolf* changes to *wolves*, so *werewolf* will change to *werewolves*. There is a list at [en.wictionary.com](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_irregular_plurals_ending_in_%22-ves%22) which includes quite a few of these kinds of compounds.

To pluralize the other words ending in **f** or **fe,** simply add **s**.

Comment: Yes, *themself* and *ourself* are words. *Them* can be just as singular as *you* can be, and nobody says that *yourself* must be written *yourselves* when only one person is involved.  A similar story can be told for *ourself*.

Comment: You forgot *life, corf, scarf, wharf*; also sometimes *staff*, *beef*, and *oaf*.

Comment: @tchirst  Thanks for the additional words. I edited to add life, corf, scarf, wharf. I guess I should add the sometimes words as well. I'm a little confused by your self-selves info. You may be correct, but I'm not getting *themself* or *ourself*. Would you please give examples?  As for *yourselves* when one person is involved, I don't suggest that, do I?

Comment: @tchrist So, I think I figured out about *themself*, as in, "Someone could finish that whole pizza themself if they wanted to." Yes?  I'm still not seeing *ourself*. And I still don't get the *yourself* comment.   Surely we'd say, "Do it yourself," if talking to one person and "Do it yourselves," if talking to two. or more.

Comment: The OED says of ***ourself***: “Emphatic and reflexive pronoun, corresponding to *we, us*, originally not differing in sense from *ourselves*; but subsequently differentiated, so as to be used mostly in those cases in which *we* refers to a single person or is not definitely plural; e.g. in royal, divine, or editorial utterance, or when used vaguely in the sense of *one, oneself.”*